# Give a specific global index to a given object based upon its type (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, static, components

I have been playing around with some simple game programming in C# with monogame and I am currently attempting to create a rudimentary ECS from scratch. I realize there are already existing very well made ECS libraries this is more a personal learning exercise.

The code I have at the moment is something like this;

```
public class Entity{

    private bool active;
    IComponent[] Components;
    public Entity(){
        active = true;

    }

    public AddComponent(IComponent component){

    }


    public bool Active { get => active; set => active = value; }
}
```

With IComponent being an interface for the components, and I was wondering if there existed a way to define a global array index for a specific component type when its first defined in runtime?

Like for example; If you have a Transform Component and a CollisionComponent then when the first Transform Component at runtime is defined a global index is given to every Transform Component defined after, with the collider component behaving in a similar manner but with obviously a different index number.

A c++ equivalent of what I am looking for is something like this:

```
inline ComponentID getNewComponentTypeID()
{
    static ComponentID lastID = 0u;
    return lastID++;
}

template <typename T>
inline ComponentID getComponentTypeID() noexcept
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value, "");
    static ComponentID typeID = getNewComponentTypeID();
    return typeID;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update:* Replaced with a better solution involving static property initialization.

---

If you need to track component types, you can do it using a static field initialization. It would be like that:

```
static class ComponentId
{
    static int Max = 0;
    static class Index<T> where T: IComponent
    {
        public static int Value = Interlocked.Increment(ref Max);
    }
    static public int Get<T>() where T : IComponent => Index<T>.Value;
}
```

Usage:

```
var id1 = ComponentId.Get<TransformComponent>() // 1
var id1 = ComponentId.Get<CollisionComponent>() // 2
var id3 = ComponentId.Get<TransformComponent>() // again 1
```

---

*Old answer:* For the case when you need a running index inside of each component, you can do the following:

```
static class GlobalCounter<T> where T : IComponent
{
    static int Value = 0;
    static public int GetNext() => Interlocked.Increment(ref Value);
}
```

You can use it like this: `GlobalCounter<TransformComponent>.GetNext()`. There will be a separate `Value` for each `T`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, it didnt quite do what I wanted to. if I implement that and call it as such: GlobalCounter<TestComponent1>.GetNext() GlobalCounter<TestComponent1>.GetNext() GlobalCounter<TestComponent2>.GetNext() I will get these numbers; 1, 2, 1 but the desired output would be 1, 1, 2.

Comment: @Simplexity: Oh I see, you need a _component_ number, not a running number inside a component. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Simplexity: Have a look, I've found a better solution and updated the answer.